# Amazon PHP SDK Listing Objects

Tags: php, amazon-s3

I have the need to display the bucket contents on my S3 and I am using Amazon's PHP SDK.
My code is simply

```
 $objects = $s3->list_objects("mybucket",array("max-keys"=>5));
 var_dump($objects);
```

The response I get from the server is very complicated for me to understand -
It's essence is

```
Object(CFResponse)[107]
    public 'header' => 
    array (size=11)
      'x-amz-id-2' => string      
    ...
    public 'body' => 
    object(CFSimpleXML)[106]
      public '@attributes' => 
        array (size=1)
          'ns' => string 'http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/' (length=39)
      public 'Name' => string 'cdneu.2yourfacecdn.com' (length=22)
      public 'Prefix' => 
        object(CFSimpleXML)[3]
      public 'Marker' => 
        object(CFSimpleXML)[105]
      public 'MaxKeys' => string '5' (length=1)
      public 'IsTruncated' => string 'true' (length=4)
      public 'Contents' => 
        array (size=5)
          0 => 
            object(CFSimpleXML)[104]
              ...
          1 => 
            object(CFSimpleXML)[103]
              ...
          2 => 
            object(CFSimpleXML)[102]
              ...
          3 => 
            object(CFSimpleXML)[101]
              ...
          4 => 
            object(CFSimpleXML)[100]
              ...
         public 'status' => int 200
```

I believe the part under the 'Contents' is what I'm looking for but how do I access it ? I'm used to receiving arrays where I can figure out what the keys are and how to access but this here is difficult for me , 
Any guesses?

Comment: Indenting code by 4 spaces doesn't work , any ideas why ?

Answer (score 1):

try this in order to list the key element of each object:

```
$s3 = new AmazonS3();
$objects = $s3->list_objects("YOUR BUCKET NAME",array("max-keys"=>5));
foreach ($objects->body->Contents as $item){
    print_r($item->Key."");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access contents as follows

```
$contents = $objects['Contents'];
```